# How to extract first url from short URL

Tags: java, android, http, kotlin, short-url

So I have a short URL that gives me 3 urls , and all I want is to extract the first URL that is on this image

[image]

So, from the short URL : https://myweb.attn.tv/EVD I got these 3 redirects, what I want is only to get the first one, I have tried with this code but without success

```
private fun extractUrl(url: String) {
        var address = URL(url)

        var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        try {
            connection = address.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY) as HttpURLConnection
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
            connection.connect()
            val expandedURL: String = connection.getHeaderField("Location")
            Logger.debug("Expanded URL${expandedURL} ")
            val expanded = URL(expandedURL)
            address = expanded
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            println("Problem while expanding {}$address$e")
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                //System.out.println(connection.inputStream)
            }
        }

        Logger.debug("Original URL${address} $connection.requestc")
    }
```

is there another way to extract the first redirect from this link ?

Thanks